# Use git library project in android application

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am very new in android. I am using eclipse. I was searching for `ColorPicker` preference and I accidentally noticed that it is possible to use other applications in my application. I have found a git project that is a library project and I want to use the `ColorPicker` in my project. Exactly How can I do that? 
I have searched a lot and I have imported git project by right click on my project->import->project from git->url-> ... . I have the project in my package explorer now. but How I can use that? Is what I have done true? I have study git project documentation too. But I found nothing.
Github repository address is [here](https://github.com/martin-stone/hsv-alpha-color-picker-android).
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Its structure belongs to Android Studio, if you want to implement it, please find a .jar or Eclipse structured project library

Comment: @S.W. The latest Eclipse supports Gradle projects

Comment: @S.w. Is there any way to change the structure to Eclipse structure?

Comment: Alright, I have passed my project to Android Studio at about Eclipse Mars

Comment: The real question is why did you clone the project? If you just want to use the library, then use `compile 'com.rarepebble:colorpicker:1.7.0'`

Comment: @cricket_007 Where should I use your code?

Comment: It's really simple if you learn the basics of the Android application structure... But I would honestly recommend using Android Studio instead of Eclipse. In any case, create a Gradle Android project, and you should have a `app/build.gradle` file with a `dependencies` section